# NHibernate 3.0 invalid index exception on flush turned into could not resolve property : {foreign key property}

Tags: nhibernate

Please help me figure this out.  I apologize if this is a duplicate question, but I can't seem to get anything else I'm reading to work.

I'm using NHibernate 3.0, C#, .NET Framework 4.0 and SQL Server 2005 to build a web site using ASP.NET MVC 2.
Here is the situation.  I have two tables with a parent -> child relationship.  I was getting the `Invalid index N for this SqlParameterCollection with Count=N.` exception.

After reading [Derik Whittaker's post at http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2009/03/19/nhibernate-and-invalid-index-n-for-this-sqlparametercollection-with-count-n-error.aspx](http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2009/03/19/nhibernate-and-invalid-index-n-for-this-sqlparametercollection-with-count-n-error.aspx) I realized that I had mapped the foreign key column on the child table to a property and the parent class object in the child class.  So, per Derik's post, I removed the property mapping in my hbm.xml file to the foreign key, and set the property to only get it's value from the parentEntity.PrimaryKey property.  Now I get an error stating NHibernate cannot resolve the foreign key property.

After spending most of the morning hunting around here and google, I've since added a private field to hold the foreign key in the child class and put back in the mapping to the foreign key, setting it's `access` attribute to `field`. NHibernate still cannot access the foreign key property.  Through information gleaned from some other posts I've made sure that all nullable columns in the database correspond to nullable properties in my entity classes, and I've checked to make sure there are no orphaned children in the database.  There are not, so I shouldn't be hitting a null reference when accessing the parent entity object.  I've also tried turning lazy loading off in my child entity map, hoping the issue would be that NHibernate is just not getting the parent from the database.  That was not the issue either.

When I step through my code in the debugger, the error comes up when I'm trying to project the data model into a view model.  If I go back to the original query, before the projection, and take a look at the values it pulls back from the database, I can see the foreign key property is populated!  I could see this as an issue if there were some orphaned children, but like I said before, that is not the case.  Unfortunately, I'm doing the projecting in a linq select query, so I can't see individual values as it steps through each one, so I now have no idea why it suddenly can't find the foreign key!

Unfortunately, this parent->child relationship itself is not expressed in the database.  The relationship itself is expressed entirely in my code.

Here is the relevent structure of the tables:

Parent table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[POSErrorQueue](
[HeaderID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
     ---About 75 other parent table specific columns---
CONSTRAINT [PK_POSErrorQueue] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [HeaderID] ASC
) WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Child table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[POSErrorQueueDetails](
[DetailID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[HeaderID] [int] NOT NULL,
     ---About 20 other child table specific columns---
CONSTRAINT [PK_POSErrorQueueDetails] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[DetailID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

And here are the associated classes in my code, after making all the changes I noted above:

Parent class:

```
public class POSErrorQueue
{
    public virtual Int32 HeaderID {get; set;}
    //all other table columns as properties
    public virtual IEnumerable<POSErrorQueueDetail> Details { get; set; }
}
```

Child class:

```
public class POSErrorQueueDetail
{
    private Int32 _headerId;
    public virtual Int32 DetailID { get; set; }
    public virtual Int32 HeaderID { get { return Header.HeaderID; } }
    //all other table columns as properties
    public virtual POSErrorQueue Header { get; set; }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is really relevent, but here is my viewmodel class:

```
public class POSErrorQueueViewModel
{
    public int HeaderID { get; set; }
    public int DetailID { get; set; }
    public string DistributorID { get; set; }
    public string BranchCustomerID { get; set; }
    public string InvoiceID { get; set; }
    public DateTime InvoiceDate { get; set; }
    public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
    public string DentsplyProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductSource { get; set; }
    public string ErrorDescription { get; set; }
    public decimal? Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal? UnitSalePrice { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalLinePrice
    {
        get
        {
            if (Quantity.HasValue && UnitSalePrice.HasValue)
            {
                return Quantity.Value * UnitSalePrice.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    public string OrderType { get; set; }
}
```

Here are my mapping files:

Parent map:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="TPMControlPanel" namespace ="TPMControlPanel.Models">
  <class name="POSErrorQueue" table="POSErrorQueue">
    <id name="HeaderID">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <!--all other property mappings removed for brevity -->
    <set name="Details" inverse="true">
      <key column="HeaderID" />
      <one-to-many class="POSErrorQueueDetail"/>
    </set>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Child map:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="TPMControlPanel" namespace ="TPMControlPanel.Models">
  <class name="POSErrorQueueDetail" table="POSErrorQueueDetails">
    <id name="DetailID">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="_headerId" column="HeaderID" access="field" />
    <!--all other property mappings removed for brevity -->
    <many-to-one name="Header" class="POSErrorQueue" column="HeaderID" fetch="join" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

For the ommitted property mappings, the name of the property and the associated column in the table are identical.

And finally, here is the code that actually generates the error:

```
public IList<POSErrorQueueViewModel> GetFiltered(Models.FilterModels.POSErrorFilterFields filterFields, DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
    {
        var query = MvcApplication.DENTSPLYSession.Query<POSErrorQueueDetail>().Where(d => d.InvoiceDate > fromDate &&
            d.InvoiceDate < toDate);
        //About 20 lines of if statements used to filter the query removed for brevity.
        var detailView = query.Select(e => new POSErrorQueueViewModel
        {
            HeaderID = e.HeaderID,
            DetailID = e.DetailID,
            BranchCustomerID = e.Header.BranchCustomerID,
            DistributorID = e.Header.DistributorID,
            DentsplyProductID = e.DentsplyProductID,
            ErrorDescription = e.ErrorDescription,
            InvoiceID = e.InvoiceID,
            InvoiceDate = e.InvoiceDate.Value,
            OrderType = e.OrderType,
            ProductDescription = e.ProductDescription,
            ProductSource = e.ProductSource,
            Quantity = e.Quantity,
            UnitSalePrice = e.UnitSalePrice
        });

        return detailView.ToList();
    }
```

Like I commented above, I've removed some code I use to filter the end result.  It's nothing but a bunch of if statements going through the values contained in the passed in `filterFields` variable and adding to the linq query.  I can post it if anyone thinks it's necesary, but the error occurs on the first time I hit the page that shows this data, before any filter values are present.

If I can offer any more information, please let me know.

Thank you,

John Norcott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still have the foreign key (HeaderID) mapped and in your model. You should have either HeaderID or Header as a property but not both.

Remove it from the model:

```
public class POSErrorQueueDetail
{
    public virtual Int32 DetailID { get; set; }
    public virtual POSErrorQueue Header { get; set; }
}
```

To access HeaderID just access Header.HeaderID. And the mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="TPMControlPanel" namespace ="TPMControlPanel.Models">
  <class name="POSErrorQueueDetail" table="POSErrorQueueDetails">
    <id name="DetailID">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <!--all other property mappings removed for brevity -->
    <many-to-one name="Header" class="POSErrorQueue" column="HeaderID" fetch="join" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: That did it!  Thanks!  A question that this brings up, though, is how would I move one detail line to another header, if that were required, since I'm no longer mapping the detailLine.HeaderID column in the database?  This isn't an issue I have at this time, more of a curiosity that this solution brings up.

Comment: It's going to depend on your implementation, but basically you remove a detail line from one header's detail collection and add it to the other header's detail collection. Along the way the detail's reference to the header must be changed.